# Change value of keys in JSON while iterating

Tags: json, python-3.x, loops

I need to loop through JSON, and replace a key name, as well as a nested key name within that key name, with new key names. 
I want to change the name peach here, to kiwi, and siteID, to siteId

I've tried setting, getting, not sure how to get it to save?

```
         "config": {
          stuff: stuff
        },
        "precheck": {
          "enabled": true,
          "networks": {
            "apple": {
              "enabled": true,
            "peach": {
              "enabled": true,
              "siteID": "100",
              "timeout": 300
            },
            "watermelon": {
              "enabled": true,
          }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assign the old value to the new keyname by using pop function

```
A = your_dict
# changing peach => kiwi    
A['precheck']['networks']['apple']['kiwi'] = A['precheck']['networks']['apple'].pop('peach')    
# changing siteID => siteId
A['precheck']['networks']['apple']['kiwi']['siteId'] = A['precheck']['networks']['apple']['kiwi'].pop("siteID")
```